# MySQL 5.5 LONGBLOB Column Data too long for column 'x' at row 1

Tags: mysql, blob, mysql-connector, maxlength

I have a column in my MySQL database that stores images as a byte array.

I am trying to update a row to insert a new image. The new image is 163K, and when I convert it to a byte[], the number of elements in the array is 167092. When I run the stored procedure that does the update, I get an error **"Data too long for column 'x' at row 1.** I already have an existing image in the database that has 8844 byte[] elements when converted.

The column datatype is LONGBLOB. From my understanding, I should have appox 4Gb to work with.

I have tried updating my my.ini file to make the MAX_ALLOWED_PACKETS=16M and I even tried 100M.

I am using the MySQL .NET Connector libraries to execute my stored procedures.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this issue? I know I could store the image paths instead of storing the images directly into the database. But I would like to know how to solve my current issue and still store the images in the database first before trying to change my approach.

Comment: I am able to upload images through MySQL workbench and everything works fine. I've been able to upload files that are 3Mb, much bigger than the 163K file I'm trying to upload through .NET. This leads me to believe it could be an issue with the MySQL connector library.

Comment: I ended up going with storing the paths in the database. But if anyone comes up with a good answer, please comment. I'd love to hear any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same problem...

In my case I was passing the LONGBLOB via a TEXT parameter since I wanted to use CONCAT inside the stored procedure in order to create dynamic SQL.

The solution was simply to change TEXT into LONGTEXT. That's it :)
That really took some time to figure out...

Hope I could help even after almost three years.